# Pandas error cannot convert String to Float setting a value at index

Tags: python, json, pandas, screen-scraping

that I know this was working for me last time I ran my script. but it looks like is not anymore. I have a scraping module which returns a dict, at my main script im running the **scraping** and assigning values . but now im getting this error about cannot convert a the string value to a float ( should i set the column to string from the very beginning ? )

This is the error

```
dataset.at[index,'UserPhotoUrl'] = scrapedData['usernamePhotoLink']
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'https://instagram.fhex4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/81572390_579207132636171_1735861275205828608_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhex4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=EfweZRX7mn8AX8kKx7e&oh=b7cb7aaf3ee583604e4a40cd7b23447f&oe=5EA1B8F7'

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and providing a [mcve] with sample input, sample output, and a reproducible amount of code

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the scrapedData explicitly to a string?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(openFilename, delimiter = ',',encoding = my_encoding, dtype={'UserPhotoUrl': str, 'PostPhotoUrl': str})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! yeah it didn't work..  I get  dataset.at[index,'UserPhotoUrl'] = scrapedData['usernamePhotoLink'].astype('str')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: also tried.. dataset.at[index,'UserPhotoUrl'] = "hello".astype('str')

Comment: could it be pandas version, I don't know If I was on a version and maybe I got an update or something....

Comment: well that says the scrapedData is already a string then.  so I would try setting `df.astype({'UserPhotoUrl': 'str'})`

Comment: dataset.at[index,'UserPhotoUrl'] = "hello" also not working , lol

Comment: let me check! im setting this columns at the beginning before processing, scrapping..  dataset = pd.read_csv(openFilename, delimiter = ',',encoding = my_encoding)
    dataset.astype({'UserPhotoUrl': 'str'})
    dataset.astype({'postPhotoLink': 'str'})

Comment: now that I have more code from your answer; see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, I did find the solution. doesn't look as elegant though .

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(openFilename, delimiter = ',',encoding = my_encoding)
dataset['UserPhotoUrl'] = " "
dataset['PostPhotoUrl'] = " "
dataset.astype({'UserPhotoUrl': 'str'})
dataset.astype({'PostPhotoUrl': 'str'})
```

Had to set at the very beginning forcing to str.